# Pandoc: Preserve whitespace in inline code

Tags: pandoc

With default settings, Pandoc converts the following Markdown snippet

```
hello` 42 `world
```

to

```
<p>hello<code>42</code>world</p>
```

As the example shows, the spaces at the beginning and end of the code block were removed. Is there a way to preserve the spaces around the inline code block (i.e. avoid trimming the code block string)?

There are many questions about preserving whitespaces with Pandoc but I did not find a good answer. For my use case, I only need *a single space per side* to be preserved to allow word-wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing white-space in inline code will always be stripped in pandoc's Markdown, no exceptions. The way to work around this is to use [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBSP)   instead of a normal space.

The alternative is to use CommonMark (e.g., by specifying `-f commonmark_x` on the command line). This is a more standardized Markdown variant, but pandoc still provides many extensions. The only major downside to this is that you can no longer use citations (like `@Smith2022`), as the respective pandoc extension has not yet been ported to CommonMark.